# Table Value Parameter missing data table data

Tags: vb.net, parameters, sql-server-express, table-valued-parameters

I'm new to TVP in SQL Server and trying to understand the basics. I created a sample TVP in the Northwind database in SQL Express. My code from VB.NET is fairly simple (see below). The TVP parameter is empty in the procedure. I've tested the TVP in SQL Server and it works fine. Any ideas? Does SQL Express fully support table value parameters?

```
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.Add("RegionID", GetType(Int64))
    dt.Columns.Add("RegionDesc", GetType(String))
    dt.Rows.Add(21, "FromProgram2")
    dt.Rows.Add(22, "FromProgram3")

    Try
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim mycommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
            Dim myconn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connstring)
            mycommand.CommandText = "dbo.TestType"
            mycommand.Connection = myconn
            Dim param1 As SqlParameter = mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegionData", dt)
            param1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured
            param1.TypeName = "dbo.RegionType"
            mycommand.Connection.Open()
            mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            mycommand.Connection.Close()
            Console.WriteLine("")
            Console.ReadLine()
        Else
            Console.Write("No data in datatable")
            Console.ReadLine()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It was an issue with my set-up at home.